# Swoole error 9009 message from Server process timer, not a Worker process callback?

Tags: php, websocket, swoole

I use Swoole as a WebSocket server. Once per second I need to broadcast a message to all connected WS clients.

Naive approach: I set a server timer `$server->tick()` prior to launching a server:

```
$this->server->tick(1000, function () {
    $message = 'hello';
    foreach ($this->server->connections as $fd) {
        $this->server->push($fd, $message);
    }
});
```

Got errors:

> [2020-05-05 12:23:56 #21985.2]  ERROR   swServer_tcp_send (ERRNO 9009)
>       can't send data to the connections in master process

What is the correct way to push WebSocket messages not from a Master, but from a Worker process?

Comment: [LINK](https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/modules/swoole-server-sendMessage) "sendMessage is blocking In the worker process"

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks.  My case is not `sendMessage()` to WorkerProcess, but rather the `Swoole\WebSocket\Server->push()`

Comment: So possible [here](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src/issues/2019)?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini indeed!   Thanks!
I came up to the similar solution, but with added singularity check: second parameter of the `onWorkerStart(\Swoole\Websocket\Server $server, int $worker_id)` should be `0` so that only one timer is launched.